# SQL trigger to prevent bit column from being updated from 1 to 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given a column with bit type in SQL Server 2008, how can I write a trigger to allow updates from 0 to 1, but disallow updating from 1 to 0?

In other words, once the bit is set to 1, it should always be 1.

The trigger must work for multiple updates, e.g. :

```
UPDATE Table SET BitField = 0
```

Should fail for any row where BitField = 1.

EDIT: To give some background, the bit/flag in question marks whether or not a monetary transaction needs to be processed.  If the bit =1, the transaction has already been processed.  If the bit is reset to 0, the transaction may be duplicated, so I need to enforce at the database level that the bit can not be reset to 0.

I need to protect against direct queries run against the database as well as application level bugs.  I can't be sure that a stored procedure will always be used to update the table, so I believe a trigger is the only way to enforce this logic.

Comment: Take a look to an `INSTEAD OF` trigger

Comment: This is a free code-vending machine!

Comment: @HLGEM - sometimes a question is simple but far enough outside the knowledge base of the poster they don't know what to try - that's ok.

Comment: @HLGEM, I have tried a few things and can write a simple trigger, but I can't get the conditional "If updated value = 0 and existing value =1, ignore update" part correct.  I could have muddied up the question with my failed attempts, but thought it would be more concise to just ask the question... sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are in need of a simple after trigger

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
    PK int Primary key,
    bitCol bit
)

CREATE TRIGGER YourTableTrigger
   ON  YourTable
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

    DECLARE @nrOfViolations int 

    select @nrOfViolations = count(*) from deleted  d
    join YourTable t on d.PK = t.PK
    where d.bitCol = 1 and t.bitCol = 0

    if @nrOfViolations > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Failed', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

Comment: If you want to optimize it and are not interested in the number of violations you can use the EXISTS operator.

Comment: I would in fact implement this using EXISTS. On the other hand, if the OP ever decides to log failed updates, it might be useful to know the number of violations, and your answer shows how to get that number.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be an instead of trigger that lets all the updates through except anything that changes the bitfield once it's equal to 1.  In that case it lets all the updates through except the bitfield change.

```
CREATE TRIGGER OneWayBitChange
   ON YourTable
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN   
UPDATE YourTable SET  /* update all fields from original update except bitfield */
    Field1 = i.Field1,
    Field2 = i.Field2,
    Field3 = i.Field3
FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.PrimaryKey = YourTable.PrimaryKey

UPDATE YourTable SET  /* update bitfield only if it's not already a 1 */
    BitField = i.BitField
FROM YourTable
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.PrimaryKey = YourTable.PrimaryKey
WHERE IsNull(YourTable.BitField,0) < 1 
END
GO
```

The above will allow all updates accept the one field when going from 1 to anything else (0, or null).

If you want to cancel any update on that row when an attempt is made on the bit field you can modify the body like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET  /* update all except bitfield changes from 1 to 0 */
    Field1 = i.Field1,
    Field2 = i.Field2,
    Field3 = i.Field3,
    BitField = i.BitField
FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.PrimaryKey = YourTable.PrimaryKey
      WHERE IsNull(BitField,0) = 0 OR IsNull(i.BitField,0) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bury it in a Trigger. I'd have your stored procedure (SP) that updates the table do a check on the value. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_update_my_table 
    @id             AS INT,
    -- Whatever other params you need
    @the_bit_field  AS BIT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @existing_value AS BIT

SELECT @existing_value = the_bit_field FROM dbo.Table1 t WHERE t.id = @id

IF @existing_value = 1 AND @the_bit_field = 0
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Fail.', 10, 1)
    RETURN -1
    END

-- Update the table as normal.

END
GO
```

Using a Trigger is kind of like trying to get the thief (the error) out of the house after he got in through the open front door (the SP's query). Lock the front door instead ;)

Comment: Excellent point +1 - I got too caught up in the actual question.

Comment: @HardCode, Great point, but I'm trying to prevent someone from executing a query directly (through SSMS or otherwise).  My application already enforces the necessary logic for users, so I'm more concerned with someone, perhaps accidentally, changing the data with a direct query like "UPDATE Table SET BitField = 0." I probably should have included that info in the question.

Comment: Then in that case, yes, you'll need a Trigger.